# bbding package not found for texlive (ubuntu)

Tags: symbols, texlive, bbding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\start{document}
\Plane
\end{document}
```

**When using XeTex or pdfLatex compiling for the above, I keep receiving the error:**

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bbding.sty' not found.
```

From the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
```

`$ locate bbding.sty` gives:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-bbding.sty
```

Using package `lwarp-bbding` does not solve the issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the `texlive-fonts-extra` package installed from Ubuntu.

`locate` is not the good way to check if a (LaTeX) package is installed, use `kpsewhich` instead

```
kpsewhich bbding.sty
```

To find out which Ubuntu package have to be installed to get bbding, use the commande `apt-file`

```
apt-file search bbding.sty
```